# What does AsynchDNS do in php?

Tags: php, curl

I was comparing two PHP configurations and i found out that `AsynchDNS` is enabled in one and not in the other under curl. What exactly does `AsynchDNS` do? I have tried google but there are many link on how enable or disable it, but not for what exactly does it do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AsynchDNS (as the name suggests) allows curl to runs DNS queries asynchronously (not as blocking calls).  In theory, this allows you to request/load multiple pages quickly as you're not waiting for each response to run in serial.

Comment: Is it advantageous to the webapp performance? I am new to PHP. My application is near to definition of online exam for the user and using lots of AJAX calls.

Comment: It depends on what's doing your calls.  If you're doing lots of connections out to remote hosts via PHP (that require DNS lookups), you may see some improvement.  However, if you're calling remote hosts via AJAX, that's up to the browser to handle - not PHP or that curl setting.